# How to use filteredArrayUsingPredicate to filter UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, grouping

Thank you for helping out in advance.

Trying to Autogroup UITableView alphabetically by following this solution: [yasirmturk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377254/autogroup-uitableview-alphabetically) But I am stuck at this part where he said:

> After that filter by alphabets:

```
NSArray *sectionArray = [vendorList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.sections objectAtIndex:section]]]; 
        rowCount = [sectionArray count];
```

**Question**: Where should I put the NSArray *sectionArray code? More specifically?

**Current Status**:[Current Status (repeated array without filtering)](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/iOSSimulatorScreenshotDec2201352742PM_zps7d331c17.png)

**Expected Result**:

1) "Egg Benedict" should be under "E" section and "Ham and Egg Sandwich" under "H" section.

Comment: @yasirmturk mind to help out?

Comment: Got it by adding it in 

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

and 

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

=)

Answer (score 1):

Got it by adding it in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(self.isFiltered){
        NSArray *filteredSectionArray = [filteredTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [arrSectionsHeader objectAtIndex:section]]];
        return [filteredSectionArray count];
    }
    else{
        NSArray *sectionArray = [allTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [arrSectionsHeader objectAtIndex:section]]];
        return [sectionArray count];
    }
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//....
    if (isFiltered) {
        NSArray *filteredSectionArray = [filteredTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [arrSectionsHeader objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
        cell.nameLabel.text =[filteredSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        NSArray *sectionArray = [allTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [arrSectionsHeader objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
//....
}
```

=)